# Basic property of Gromov-witten invariant

Tags: gromov-witten-theory

[image]

I am reading 'An invitation to Quantum cohomology by J.Kock, I.vainsencher'.

I added a picture of the page on which I have question.

The projection is flat and therefore has positive relative (fiber) dimension.

How is this fact related that the direct image is zero?

Should I just consider intersection theory?

Comment: It would help if you include more context instead of embedding a scanned excerpt from a book.

Comment: The proper pushforward map in homology, resp. Chow groups, is a graded homomorphism that preserves the homological degree, i.e., $H_q(\overline{M}_{0,n}\times \mathbb{P}^r)\to H_q(\mathbb{P}^r)$, resp. $\text{CH}_p(\overline{M}_{0,n}\times \mathbb{P}^r)\to \text{CH}_p(\mathbb{P}^r)$.  The fundamental class of $\overline{M}_{0,n}\times \mathbb{P}^r$ is in degree $2(r+(n-3))$, resp. in $\text{CH}_{r+(n-3)}(\overline{M}_{0,n}\times \mathbb{P}^r)$.  Since the homology groups, resp. Chow groups, of $\mathbb{P}^r$ vanish in degrees $>2r$, resp. $>r$, the pushforward is nonzero if and only if $n=3$.